# MongoDB remove returning nRemoved 0

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am running a remove command against the Mongo Shell which doesn't seem to remove any documents:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin>mongo outputcachedb --eval "db.CacheItem
s.remove({ "Expiration" : { "$lte" : new Date() } });"
2015-04-22T11:30:30.957+0200 I CONTROL  Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is not
installed, will zero-out data files
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.2
connecting to: outputcachedb
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 0 })
```

If I run the same query document using MongoVue it finds (and when requested removes) documents

Answer (score 3):

That is because you have incorrect procedure to delete collection.

Solution and Example:

1- C:\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongo (do not issue command yet because you are not connected to any database yet, you are only connected to database server mongodb).

2-

> show dbs
>   analytics_database  0.000GB
>   local               0.000GB
>   test_database       0.000GB

3-

> use test_database
>   switched to db test_database

4-

> db.Collection.remove({"_id": ObjectId("5694a3590f6d451c1500002e")}, 1);
>   WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 1 })

now you see WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 1 }) is 1 not 0.

Done.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why --eval does not work, but I could get this to work by running an external .js file into the shell.

```
db.CacheItems.remove({ "Expiration" : { "$lte" : new Date() } });
```

goes into remove.js and then

```
$ mongo outputcachedb remove.js
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: Well, I think it worked for me as in my answer, but you might want to try setting 'db' explicitly --> db = db.getSisterDB('outputcachedb') and... assigning new Date() --> var d = new Date().        I find that in mongoshell sometimes my queries don't like it when I use new Date() straight. Tell me if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried these suggestions. Its seems like the shell syntax is case sensitive (or at least the database identifier is). So "outputcachedb" needed to be "OutputCacheDB". I expect I should have RTFM